# Batch Script to copy a subfolder to another folder using the subfolder name

Tags: batch-file, copy

I need to copy folder and its contents to target folder Using Batch Scripting.

For Example ,
we have folder named "ParentFolder" and inside this folder we have "Child1" folder and inside this i have a text file.

Target folder is named as "Targetfolder"

I want to 1st check if the subfolder of "Parentfolder" is "Child1" folder and then copy the whole folder "Child1" to "Targetfolder"

***EDIT - Added code from comment***

```
@echo on
set FOLDER1=c:\Temp\FOLDER1
set FOLDER2=c:\Temp\FOLDER2
if exist %FOLDER1% ( xcopy /Q /D /S /V %FOLDER1% %FOLDER2% )
:END
```

Comment: Show us what code you have so far and then we can help you.

Comment: `@echo on

set FOLDER1=c:\Temp\FOLDER1
set FOLDER2=c:\Temp\FOLDER2

if exist %FOLDER1% (

xcopy /Q /D /S /V %FOLDER1% %FOLDER2%

)

:END              `         I want only selected folders inside FOLDER1, FOLDER1 has several folders

Comment: Thanku Bali C for helping with editing :)

Comment: Folder1 is parent folder
Folder2 is target folder

Comment: So, what isn't working for you? I'm not clear on what your question is.

Comment: Files inside FOLDER1 is being copied, but not including FOLDER1

suppose,
before copy.....

`FOLDER1 `
`-CHILD1`
`-CHILD2`
`FOLDER2 (empty)`

after copy
`Folder2` shud caontain `FOLDER1` and then `CHILD1` and `CHILD2`


But what i am getting is 
FOLDER2
    -CHILD1
    -CHILD2

Comment: @aphoria : pls read the above cooment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, you want to copy the folder `Parent (Child 1, Child 2)` into `Target ( Empty )` so that the resulting copy becomes `Target ( Parent ( Child 1, Child 2) )`?

If so then you need to add the parent name to the target path because xcopy only copies the contents of the source directory into the specified target directory.  Be sure to have a backslash at the end of the target path to signify that it is a directory and not a file.  Else you will be prompted.

```
@echo on
set SOURCENAME=FOLDER1
set FOLDER1=c:\Temp\%SOURCENAME%
set FOLDER2=c:\Temp\FOLDER2
if exist %FOLDER1% ( xcopy /Q /D /S /V %FOLDER1% %FOLDER2%\%SOURCENAME%\ )
:END
```

Comment: :Thanku fr trying the solution :) ,
I wanted   ` target ( Child1,Child2)`